# python shapely: retrieve the x,y,z value of a LinearRing

Tags: python, shapely

I`m trying to plot a LinearRing that shows the difference  of the crossover of two Polygons:

```
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as a3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

poly1 = Polygon([(220.0, 780, 500), (840, 780, 500), (840, 180, 500), (220.0, 180, 500)])
poly2 = Polygon ([(320.0, 380, 500), (740, 380, 500), (740, 180, 500), (320.0, 180, 500)])

dif = poly1.difference(poly2)
```

I`d like to plot dif, however, when using:

```
top1 = a3.art3d.Poly3DCollection([dif],alpha=0.6)
```

I get an erros saying "TypeError: 'Polygon' object is not iterable"

I therefore try to get the x,y,z coordinates of dif and plot them, but I`ve only managed to get the x,y ones. For the sake of testing, I currently feed-in the Z value manualy:

```
z= [500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500] 
x,y = a.exterior.xy

zipped = list(zip (x,y,z))
top1 = a3.art3d.Poly3DCollection([zipped],alpha=0.6)   
top1.set_color('wheat')
top1.set_edgecolor('k')        
ax.add_collection3d(top1)

ax.set_xlim(0, 1000)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1000)
ax.set_zlim(0, 1000)
plt.show()
```

I then get the  plot I am after, but I`m looking for an easier way to plot dif.

Answer (score 1):

With the `exterior` attribute you are using, you can get the coords:

```
top1 = a3.art3d.Poly3DCollection([dif.exterior.coords],alpha=0.6)
```

Beware, with this code and also with your solution, you are loosing the interior rings of the polygon, if there are any.

Notice that `coords` returns an iterable, if you want a list you must create it (`list(dif.exterior.coords)`).

For a polygon with interior rings, you could handle it as in this example:

```
poly = Point(0,0).buffer(500)
poly = Polygon([ (x, y, 500) for x, y in poly.exterior.coords ])
spoly = Point(0,0).buffer(200)
spoly = Polygon([ (x, y, 500) for x, y in spoly.exterior.coords ])
poly = poly.difference(spoly)

all_coords = [p.coords for p in poly.interiors]
all_coords.append(poly.exterior.coords)
top1 = a3.art3d.Poly3DCollection(all_coords,alpha=0.6)
```

IMHO, using shapely with 3D polygons is misleading, since shapely only handles 2D polygons, and will bring you problems if you spread the 3D part all over the code that uses Shapely. Besides, someone reading the code could think you are actually doing 3D math when you are not. Perhaps you can isolate all 2D computation with shapely, and after that add it the 3D part.